# Casting value to be returned to a Generic type in c#

Tags: c#

Example function:

```
// return true if data was able to be fetched into res.  
private bool TryGetData<T>(out T res)
{
    res = default(T);
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        DateTime dtRes = DateTime.Now;  // do some work to get required data.  
        res = (T)(object)dtRes;

        return true;
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        string strRes = "hello world"; // do some work to get required data.  
        res = (T)(object)strRes;

        return true;
    }

    return false; 
}
```

Example calls to function:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dtRes;
    if (TryGetData(out dtRes))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("result " + dtRes);
    }

    string strRes;
    if (TryGetData(out strRes))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("result " + strRes);
    }
}
```

So TryGetData does different things, depending on the type of T. My question is regarding the lines where "res" is set, where a double cast has been used. Is there a better way of performing the assignment to res ? e.g. maybe by using System.Convert.ChangeType, or something else.

Comment: don't use **generics** for something that is ment to work for **specific** types. Just make different overloads excepting different types.

Comment: The worst thing about generic methods like this is that they lie to the future programmer. "I can work with absolutely any type `T`" is what that method declares by its generic type constraints, but then in the vast majority of cases it's a guaranteed fail at runtime. Which wastes everyone's time.

Comment: The reason you need a double cast is that there is no constraint on T, so the runtime can't know the reolashionshipt between you concrete type and T. A downcast into object, allows to recast to T because nearly everything inherits from object. THough that cast would throw at runtime if the types were not compatible.
I do agree that in this instance multiple overloads accpeting different types would be clearer both for maintenance, and for the developer who would want to use the method

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? How is the data produced? It is not that uncommon when deserializing data to tell a method, 'Here is some piece of data, convert it to an object of this type', but the developer then makes the implicit promise that the data *actually* represent that type. But it is difficult to tell from your example if that is appropriate for this case.

Comment: @JonashH - the data is being read from an Excel spreadsheet.  So the real "TryGetData" function would have cell location info passed to it as parameters. And the returned res would be the value of the cell.  Some processing needs to be done to read the cell values in the desired way.

Comment: If you look at the implementation you've shown, you'll see that there's *no common code* between the two types you can work with. Effectively this is two methods, `TryGetDateTime` and `TryGetString` in disguise.